# Power set of a given set

Tags: c, algorithm

Given a set I want to display all its subsets (its power set). I have found this code:

```
void printPowerSet(char *set, int set_size)
{
    /*set_size of power set of a set with set_size
      n is (2**n -1)*/
    unsigned int pow_set_size = pow(2, set_size);
    int counter, j;

    /*Run from counter 000..0 to 111..1*/
    for(counter = 0; counter < pow_set_size; counter++)
    {
      for(j = 0; j < set_size; j++)
       {

          if(counter & (1<<j))
            printf("%c", set[j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this part is used

```
 if(counter & (1<<j))
```

what is its meaning?

The time complexity for this algorithm is `O(n2^n)`  is there any better method?

Comment: This translates to this: if `counter`, bitwise has bit nbr. `j` set to 1, then ...

Comment: The size of the output is O(n*2^n), so there can't be an asymptotically faster method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `if` checks if bit `j` is set.  For example, when `j == 0` we're looking at (I'm using 8 bits for simplicity):

```
XXXXXXX? & 00000001
```

where `X` is "don't care", `?` is what we want to check.  Then when `j == 1`

```
XXXXXX?X & 00000010
```

In other words, it's a convenient way to check if a bit is set or unset, which determines whether the corresponding set element is included in the current set or not.

As for complexity, since there are `2^n` sets in a power set, it's hard to imagine a faster algorithm for generating them all.

The reason this generates a power set is that a binary counter exhausts all combinations of `n` bit values, see the following for an example.

***Example***

set: {1, 2, 3}

```
counter    1<<j   intermediate result   final
    000    001    N/A
    000    010    N/A
    000    100    N/A
                                        {}
    001    001    3
    001    010    N/A
    001    100    N/A
                                        {3}
    < ... skip a few iterations ... >
    101    001    3
    101    010    N/A
    101    100    1
                                        {1,3}
    < ... etc ... >
```

Comment: why to use left shifter  <<

Comment: `1` is a value with all bits 0 except the least significant. Shifting left by `n` bits results in a value with only the `nth` bit set -- it allows for computing the appropriate bitmask based on the `j` counter's value.

Comment: @FatalError  you are good but would you explain with a simple example {a,b,c} things will be more clear

Comment: Sure, that's not a bad idea... example added.

Answer (score 1):

This code below will stop faster than the above algorithm.

Complexity wise, your assessment is correct as O(N*2^N) is the size of the output.

```
unsigned c;
for (counter = 0; counter < pow_set_size; counter++) {

    for (c = counter; c != 0; ) {
        if( c & 1 ) {
            printf("%c", set[j]);
        }
        c = c >> 1; // drop lsb
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```